# Pixel-Accurate UIImage Resampling in UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'd like to know how can I up-size a UIImage in a UIButton so that when it is scaled up to fill the button, it has sharp edges, instead of blurry?

I.e for use in 8-bit styled artwork. The UIImage I have saved is 64px by 64 px, but is being displayed on a much larger frame.

```
let imageToDisplay = UIImage(named: "PixelImage")
theButton.setBackgroundImage(imageToDisplay, for: .normal)
```

The images below show how the image is meant to be upsized, but then also what it currently looks like on the button:
[image: Correct Resizing]
[image: Incorrect resizing]

Comment: Turn off antialiasing and redraw larger yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself by resizing the UIImage to the size of the UIButton with antialiasing turned off.

Comment: I believe that's what I said.

Comment: Correct, you did also state something that I had already done prior to reading your comment. Your comment which gave no direction, tips or example code on how to actually accomplish that. But thanks.

Comment: Also for simple shape/images like that, you should just use SVGs

Comment: Not when the image is stored on a server and its not possible to produce svg artwork.